# Neural network initialization behavior: low initial loss that spikes, then slowly decreases

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions, tensorflow

[image]
The embedded image is the training loss of my inception V3 architecture that I am training from scratch using the sigmoid cross-entropy loss function and the Tensorflow RMSProp optimizer with two classes in my data. The x axis is batch index. I am initializing my inception V3 using `tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3` (with random weights). However, I have also seen this loss curve behavior in other architectures of neural network with random weight initialization, Tensorflow versions, and datasets.

My question is why the loss starts out so low, and then spikes up only to decrease again? Wouldn't this mean that the weights are improperly initialized?

Update: the loss is spiking at every start of an epoch of my dataset. This must be my user error. My dataset is well-shuffled. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the loss function include any regularization terms? Does the behavior persist when using optimizers other than RMSProp?

Comment: Inception has some batch normalization layers, but I did not add any regularizers to my model. I also have seen this behavior on different model architectures, and while using the Adam optimizer. Additionally, now that the model has been training for a few epochs, I have noticed the same behavior at the start of each epoch. It spikes up, and then goes back down. So I guess this must not have anything to do with weight initialization. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Since it occurs at the beginning of an epoch, I wonder if it's an effect from having a *last* batch in an epoch with a dramatically different size (e.g. 1002 training instances with batch size 100), or if it's due to not shuffling the training data at each epoch.

Comment: I'm shuffling my dataset pretty well before I start training, and I'm using the tf.data.Dataset.batch(drop_remainder=True), so every batch should be the same size. I'll try shuffling at each epoch to see if its a batching thing. I am curious if this  has anything to do with the batch normalization values not saving and restoring across epochs.